# How can I share individual windows or a specific display with Google Hangouts?

Tags: release-freya, google-chrome

I'm having problems with screen share on Google Hangouts. When I click screen share I can only share my entire screen.

I would like to share individual windows or one specific monitor.

Comment: Can you edit your question to clarify what you want to do? At the moment I only know what you can already do, but that it isn't what you want.

Comment: Can you please add information about installed Google Hangouts plugin? In Firefox it's shown in about:plugins page. There should be section with Google Talk Plugin and Google Talk Plugin Video Renderer. How did you installed the plugin?

Comment: I'm having the problem on Google Chrome as well. (Which doesn't require a plugin)

Comment: It works for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that screen sharing is somehow limited or broken when using Hangouts without the plugin. I have got the plugin installed and screen sharing of individual windows is working fine in both Chromium and Firefox. I tried to disable the plugin in Chromium (43) and screen sharing didn't work at all (this is probably related to another issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=413942). I would recommend you to install the latest plugin.

1. Go to http://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangout/download.html?hl=en and download the Debian/Ubuntu package. Check the System Settings > About if you do not know if you need 32bit or 64bit version.
2. Install the downloaded package, using the Software Center for example. It should be enough to click the package in Files and press the Install button.
3. Restart the browser and check if you see the Google Talk in plugin list.

   - Firefox: Tools > Add-ons > Plugins
   - Chrome/Chromium: Open chrome://plugins/

Now the plugin should be used for Hangouts. Please send us more information if the screen sharing is still not working for you.

A note to sharing a specific monitor: I think it's possible to share just a specific window or the whole desktop. I didn't see a possibility to share a specific monitor yet.

Comment: Do hangouts work without the plugin?

Comment: Yes, in Chrome or Chromium: http://techcrunch.com/2014/06/27/google-hangouts-will-no-longer-require-a-plugin-for-chrome-users/

Comment: Can confirm that this fixed the issue for me.